# My main div has a margin without setting it to have one

Tags: html, css

I have a div, the main div that contains everything on my website, but it adds a random margin on top, even with margins set to 0.

CSS:

```
body {
font-family:  Helvetica, serif, Arial;
min-height: 100%;
background-color: #bdc3c7;

}

#wrapper{
    margin: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #ecf0f1;
}
```

Comment: if you inspect the elements using developer tools, you will be able to see the attributes and from where they are being inherited, and/or overwritten.

Comment: by the way, your font declaration doesn't make much sense.

Comment: The best is the `*` reset solution i think

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to go all out making sure defaults get cleared out, use a [CSS Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).  However, I'm sure this is overkill for what you are doing.

Comment: Works, looks like, only needed the first tag. Hmmm, thanks I guess. But keep posting solutions if you have. Will see how this comes out. Accepted answer until I find a better one.

Answer (score 1):

Each browser has some pre-set values. Reset them:

CSS Reset (mentioned previously at http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

or

Normalize.css at https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/ can help

Answer (score 0):

In html, your body will always have a margin by default.

You should add: `margin:0;` to your body css.